# Delayed Job worker daemons randomly stop working jobs off queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, worker-process

At least once a day my Delayed::Job workers will randomly stop working jobs off the queue, yet the processes are still alive.

Pictured: "Zombies"
[image]

When I inspect the remaining jobs in the queue, none will show that they are locked/being-worked by the zombified workers in question. Even when looking at failed jobs its hard to make a definite question connection between a failure and the workers going into zombie mode.

I have a theory that a job has an error that causes workers to segfault, but not completely die. Is there any way to inspect a worker process and see what it's doing? How would one go about debugging this issue when there's not even a stacktrace or failed job to inspect?